# Python Web Socket closes immediately after opening

Tags: python, websocket

So I have an issue with a websocket in Python. I'm trying to interface with a website that uses websockets for some of its content communication. Here is the javascript code on their site:

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); // Use $j to reference JQuery selectors instead of $
 function sockify() {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://website:1234");
    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.data)
       $j('#output').html(evt.data);
    }
    ws.onopen = function () {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify($j('#srctext').val()));
    }
    ws.onerror = function () {
        alert("socket down");
    }
 }
```

So the site works fine, and theres no issue with it, however when I try this python code, I get an error stating that the socket has been closed immediately after it opens:

```
ws = create_connection("ws://website:1234/")
print "Sending 'Hello, World'..."
ws.send("Hello, World")
print "Sent"
print "Receiving..."
result = ws.recv()
print "Received '%s'" % result
ws.close()
```

This is sample code pulled from the [websocket man page on python.org](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/), and it does work if I do not change the host to the website i'm trying to pull from, but rather leave the example's host as it is in the example.

Here is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "irc.py", line 462, in <module>
    tmpmsg = getSocket()
  File "irc.py", line 64, in getTrump
    result = ws.recv()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 293, in recv
    opcode, data = self.recv_data()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 310, in recv_data
    opcode, frame = self.recv_data_frame(control_frame)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 323, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 357, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 336, in recv_frame
    self.recv_header()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 286, in recv_header
    header = self.recv_strict(2)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 371, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 427, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 93, in recv
    "Connection is already closed.")
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.
```

Any idea why its closing right away?

Edit:

Ran with enableTrace true.

Here is the error I get:

```
--- request header ---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: website
Origin: website
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 6jsV5DEWXPGTTTLKSEwz6g==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13


-----------------------
--- response header ---
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: CX4DYsItQC6utXvt8JH641455mM=
-----------------------
send: '\x81\x8b\x98\x8d\x81\xce\xd0\xe8\xed\xa2\xf7\xad\xd6\xa1\xea\xe1\xe5'
```

Please note that I dont actually have control over the websocket, so any fixes would need to be on my end. I'm on Python 2.7.10

I also noticed that if I intercept the websocket request in Burp while using the website, the websocket initial connection request is different. Here it is as captured from the website:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: website
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: website
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: uyG2WBK51ZtPhy9RXLNTmg==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

Comment: For anyone who runs into this issue, I dont have a great solution for you. I just used selenium and phantomjs to load the site, input the field, click the button, and read the response from there. So much overhead, but it worked for my little pet project.

Comment: Looks like the websocket does not like to receive `Hello, World`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have for sure an error (most probably your socket is exploding silently..)

set instead in the configuration a callback for the errors in the socket and print the msg you get..

example: (taken from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/))

```
 websocket.enableTrace(True)
 ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
```

and define the method

```
def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)
```

Comment: Did this and threw the result in my original post, at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is having the same issue I fixed it by tweaking the websocket module and setting a custom header in the get request try forcing it to use this header

`GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: website
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: website
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: uyG2WBK51ZtPhy9RXLNTmg==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket`

instead of this

`GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: website
Origin: website
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 6jsV5DEWXPGTTTLKSEwz6g==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13`

Comment: @dan its been long time since i posted this but i remmber hardcoding the header so it gets posted everytime i dont remmber where sorry